# Javascript: get iCheck radio value by name

Tags: jquery, radio-button, icheck

How to get iCheck radio value by name, like `$("input[type=radio][name=test]").val()`? Seems it is not working. Please see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkxbn3ju/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="i-checks"><label> <input type="radio" checked="" value="a" name="test"> a </label></div>
<div class="i-checks"><label> <input type="radio" value="b" name="test"> b </label></div>
<div class="i-checks"><label> <input type="radio" value="c" name="test"> c </label></div>


The <span id='outputbythis' style='color:green'></span> is checked by $(this).val()
<br>
The <span id='outputbyname' style='color:red'></span> is checked by $("input[type=radio][name=test]").val()
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',
        radioClass: 'iradio_flat-green'
    });



    $('input').on('ifToggled', function (event) {

        $("#outputbythis").text($(this).val())

        $("#outputbyname").text($("input[type=radio][name=test]").val())

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the selector will return an array.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',
        radioClass: 'iradio_flat-green'
    });



    $('input').on('ifToggled', function (event) {

        $("#outputbythis").text($(this).val())

        $("#outputbyname").text($("input[type=radio][name=test]:checked").val())

    });

});
```

this should work

Comment: How to get iCheck radio value by name?

Comment: Thanks! Really hard to figure it out by a self-learner. I mean I can't understand and aware sometimes `$("input[type=radio][name=test]")` works while sometimes `$("input[type=radio][name=test]")` has to be changed to `$("input[type=radio][name=test]:checked").val()`.